# ContextualVersionConflict when using S3 boto3 and snowflake connector

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, pip, boto3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect to Amazon S3 using `boto3` and `snowflake-connector-python` for which I am running the following packages:

```
boto3==1.14.8
botocore==1.17.8
snowflake-connector-python==2.2.7
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.3
```

I create my s3 connection via:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io

def retrieveCSV():
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id = [ACCESSKEY],
        aws_secret_access_key = [SECRETKEY],
        )

    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    obj = s3.Object('mybucket','MyData.csv')
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    dfCSV = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body),header=2)
    print(dfCSV)

    return dfCSV
```

And I connect to Snowflake using:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def createEngine(schema):
    strConn = 'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/{database}/{schema}'.format(
                        user = [MYUSER],
                        password = [MYPASSWORD],
                        account = [MYSERVER],
                        database = [MYDATABASE],
                        schema = [MYSCHEMA]
                        )
    print(strConn)

    engine = create_engine(strConn)

    return engine
```

Which causes the following error when running `create_engine`:

```
raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (boto3 1.14.8(/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('boto3<1.14,>=1.4.4'), {'snowflake-connector-python'})
```

I tried upgrading via:

```
pip3 install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python
```

which ended with a `SegFault`:

```
Installing collected packages: urllib3, six, python-dateutil, docutils, jmespath, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, idna, certifi, chardet, requests, azure-core, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, isodate, msrest, azure-storage-blob, pyjwt, asn1crypto, pytz, oscrypto, pycryptodomex, pyOpenSSL, azure-common, ijson, snowflake-connector-python
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What is the way to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the way to resolve this conflict?

You can try to follow the path of using the lowest agreeable version. To break it down:

- The `snowflake-connector-python` package dependencies appears to be restricting its use of `boto3` library to `1.13.x` at most.
- Your requirements specify an explicit version of `boto3` `1.14.x`.
- Your use of the simple `boto3` APIs (going by the snippet shared) does not appear to involve [any 1.14.x specific changes or features](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst).
- `boto3` `1.13.x` releases continue to work against the live AWS S3 service.

Therefore, try using an accepted version of [boto3](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/0356e73a57f6516ed61bca2bedb22da8d42e8747/setup.py#L174)/[botocore](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/1.13.26/setup.py#L17) in place of the current version(s):

```
boto3==1.13
botocore==1.16
snowflake-connector-python==2.2.7
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.3
```

Comment: Yup that worked. I uninstalled `boto3`, `botocore`, and `s3transfer`, then ran: `pip3 install 'boto3=1.13'` and all necessary packages were installed with the necessary version and conflicts removed.